# How to check if an item in an arrayList already exists and add count in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Assuming I had a class `Groceries(name,quantity)` and the class is used for an array list called `shoppingList`.

```
   ArrayList<Groceries> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The names and quantities of items would be stored in this array list. An item that is about to be added in this arrayList already exist but with a different quantity. How do I avoid duplicates by bypassing the name of the already existing name and just add the quantity to the existing name?

Here is my code, i'm not done yet: It is supposed to read from a data file

```
add,3,loaf of bread
add,2,jug of milk
list
buy,2,loaf of bread
add,4,loaf of bread
buy,3,jug of milk

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class A3Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader input;
        String line;
        String command, name;
        int quantity;
        //Groceries name;
        String tokens[];

        ArrayList<Groceries> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Groceries> purchaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        Groceries grocery;


        try{
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a3a.txt"));
            line = input.readLine();
            while(line!= null){
                tokens = line.split(",");
                command = tokens[0].trim();
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
                name = tokens[2].trim();

                if (command.equals("add")){
                    shoppingList.add(new Groceries(quantity,name));
                    if (command.equals("buy")){
                        purchaseList.add(new Groceries(quantity,name));
                    }
                }

            }

        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Groceries {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;


    public Groceries( int quantity, String name){
        this.name =name;
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }


}
```

requirements as requested;

> The data file used as input to the program will consist of lines containing one of three commands. The first of these is add, which is
>   followed by a quantity and an item name, separated by commas. This will add to the shopping list; if an item with that name already
>   exists, increase the quantity desired by the given number. Otherwise, add a new item to the list with that name and quantity. The
>   second command is buy, which is also followed by a quantity and an item name. This will add to the purchase list in a similar
>   fashion. Also, if an item with that name is already in the shopping list, reduce the quantity desired by that number. If the quantity of
>   that item reaches zero (or less), remove it from the shopping list. Finally, the list command should print out both lists, showing
>   both the quantity and the item name, one item per line. For example, the data file:

Comment: why bold the whole text ?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? and what are the requirements, do you must use arraylist? etc...

Comment: right. The program originally reads from a file and then add the names and quantities for these items. for example if it contains `3, bread` and `4,bread` then the output should just be `7, bread`. I can do this with ordinary arrays by using the position, arrays and size but checking in the arrayList is the problem @MrSimpleMind

Comment: @girlCoder in your case... I would, upon reading the file line by line, in that loop, as you add to the list... also put to a HashMap the item and incremental value. In this way you have entire "history" (the list) and an aggregation value for each name (from the hashmap).

Comment: I have updated the question now with the requirements and what i'm doing so far as you asked @MrSimpleMind

Comment: true. I did that but i'm still yet to know the go-abouts on hash maps @MrSimpleMind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you wish ot use ArrayList and not mix with HashMap or other Key-Value classes you will need to check with a loop if the grocery exist, and if it does then you need to remove it and add a new one with increased quantity.

You also had some code errors, please study the code bellow and try to understand it. It is the best way to learn! Not just copy-and-paste ;)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A3Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader input;
        String line;
        String command, name = null;
        int quantity = 0;
        //Groceries name;
        String tokens[];

        ArrayList<Groceries> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Groceries> purchaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        Groceries grocery = null;


        try{
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a3a.txt"));
            line = input.readLine();
            while(line!= null){
                tokens = line.split(",");
                command = tokens[0].trim();

                if(command.equals("list")) {
                  System.out.println("shoppingList " + shoppingList);
                  System.out.println("purchaseList " + purchaseList);
                  System.out.println("");
                } else {
                  quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
                  name = tokens[2].trim();
                }

                if (command.equals("add")) {
                  boolean added = false;
                  for (int i=0; i<shoppingList.size(); i++) {
                    Groceries g = (Groceries) shoppingList.get(i);
                    if( g.getName().equals(name) ){
                      shoppingList.remove(g);
                      quantity += g.getQuantity();
                      g.setQuantity(quantity);
                      shoppingList.add(g);
                      added = true;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                  if( !added ) {
                    shoppingList.add(new Groceries(quantity,name));
                  }
                }
                if (command.equals("buy")) {
                  for (int i=0; i<shoppingList.size(); i++) {
                    Groceries g = (Groceries) shoppingList.get(i);
                    if( g.getName().equals(name) ){
                      shoppingList.remove(g);
                      if( g.getQuantity() - quantity > 0 ) {
                        g.setQuantity(g.getQuantity() - quantity);
                        shoppingList.add(g);
                      } else {
                        //quantity = g.getQuantity(); //removed this as you wanted to keep the purchaselist this way
                      }
                      break;
                    }
                  }

                  boolean added = false;
                  for (int i=0; i<purchaseList.size(); i++) {
                    Groceries g = (Groceries) purchaseList.get(i);
                    if( g.getName().equals(name) ){
                      purchaseList.remove(g);
                      quantity += g.getQuantity();
                      g.setQuantity(quantity);
                      purchaseList.add(g);
                      added = true;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                  if( !added ) {
                    purchaseList.add(new Groceries(quantity,name));
                  }
                }
                line = input.readLine();
            }

        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Groceries {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;


    public Groceries( int quantity, String name){
        this.name =name;
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
      return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) { this.quantity=quantity; }

    public String toString() {
      return quantity + ", " + name;
    }
}
```

**a3a.txt**

```
add,3,bread
list
add,2,milk
list
buy,2,bread
list
add,4,bread
list
buy,3,milk
list
buy,1,butter
list
```

(I assume that list is a command that will display the lists)

**Output**

```
shoppingList [3, bread]
purchaseList []

shoppingList [3, bread, 2, milk]
purchaseList []

shoppingList [2, milk, 1, bread]
purchaseList [2, bread]

shoppingList [2, milk, 5, bread]
purchaseList [2, bread]

shoppingList [5, bread]
purchaseList [2, bread, 3, milk]

shoppingList [5, bread]
purchaseList [2, bread, 3, milk, 1, butter]
```

Comment: the `7th line` is `buy,1,stick of butter` not `buy, 1, loaf of bread` I forgot to add that. plus the items in the purchaseList do not print out their values for your code

Comment: I assume that `list` command is what you want to trigger a display of the lists. If you add list at end, it will print all as a final step. You can make a fancy display, than system.out.println the entire list.

Comment: oh! I was mistaken. The problem was on the third output where it says `shoppingList [2, jug of milk, 7, loaf of bread]` because after adding 4 loafs of bread the output should give `shoppingList [5, loaf of bread]` and no milk instead.

Comment: you have 3 loaf of breads, and then you add 4, this gives total 7 .. from what a3a.txt shows in my answer. Maybe your a3a.txt file is different.

Comment: true. we are using different text files. remove the 7th line of your a3a.txt

Comment: i'm guessing the problem starts from `if(command.equals("buy"))` because thats where the shopping list quantity should be subtracted

Comment: I didnt see the entire requirement before, so now I updated the logic so the relation between the two lists is as per requirement. Run and check if it is ok

Answer (score 2):

Use a HashMap instead:

```
Map<String, Integer> shoppingList = new HashMap<>();
shoppingList.put("Eggs", 1);

// Add more
if(shoppingList.containsKey("Eggs")){
  shoppingList.put("Eggs", shoppingList.get("Eggs") + 5);
}
```

You can easyly access specific groceries now and avoid duplicates. Of course you can also use your Groceries class instead of String, if it has more than the "name" attribute.

Comment: This person wants to add the quantity not increase  it

Comment: That wouldn't compile (`shoppingList.get("Eggs")++`)

Comment: true, there is already a quantity allocated for each item. for example `3, bread` and `4,bread` should give just `7, bread`

Comment: I added an example for this as well

Comment: You are right, the "++" wasn't compiling - I removed it.

Comment: why are you adding `5` ? @Nitek

Comment: Just an example - Add whatever you like

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ArrayList`'s [`indexOf(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method to get the index of the grocery in the list and if it returns a valid value (i.e. larger than -1), retrieve the Groceries object with [`get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) and increment / replace its quantity.

---

#### Possible gotchas & interesting things

I don't know your Groceries class' implementation details but you should mind that if you create a new Groceries object for the same grocery (i.e. with the same name) and you don't override the [`equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) (*and probably the `hashCode()` method as well because "equal objects must have equal hash codes"*) method, you'll never find duplicates in the list as the objects are being compared with their `equals` methods.

If you really want to just store the Groceries objects and enforce that only one of the same object can be in the list, you should use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) ([`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) specifically). Still keep in mind that you have to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void addGroceries(String item,Integer quantity, Map<String,Integer> shoppingList){
                    if(shoppingList.containsKey(item)){
                  Integer newQuatity =shoppingList.get(item);
                  shoppingList.remove(item);
                  shoppingList.put(item, quatity+newQuatity);
                }
                 else{
               shoppingList.put(item, quatity);
    }
```

Comment: your code is adding the quantity but it is not fulfilling the condition `Otherwise, add a new item to the list with that name and quantity.` it isn't adding a new name and quantity if it doesn't exist. Plus the class is Groceries not a String

Comment: In programming there is more than one way. Which way is good is decided by the programmer or concerned entity not by the tool. I am only try to demonstrate one of the way how Map can be used in such situation . Your situation may demand more.